# How to work with numpy.where?

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I want to find indexes of array like `x = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]])` where elements equals to `y = np.array([1, 1, 1])`. So I did this:

```
In: np.where(x == y)
Out: (array([0, 0, 0]), array([0, 1, 2]))
```

It is the correct answer. But I expect to get only index `0` because the zero element of `x` is equal to `y`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `(x == y).all(axis=1)` to reduce the comparison result over `axis=1` first, i.e *all elements are equal*:

```
np.where((x == y).all(axis=1))[0]
# array([0])
```